# jQuery create a new element with `data` HTML attribute

Tags: jquery

#### Preamble

The question is about HTML element creation with an HTML `data` attribute, like `<object data="foo"></object>`.

#### The Question

Quick question as I stumbled across this a few minutes ago; If I write

```
$('<div>', { id:"foo", 'class':"bar" });
// <div id="foo" class="bar"></div>
```

However

```
$('<object>', { id:"foo", data:"some+data+string" });
// [ <object id="foo"></object> ]
```

where I expected the output to be

```
// [ <object id="foo" data="some+data+string"></object> ]
```

I know about `.data`. My problem is that

```
$('<object>', { id:"foo", data:"some+data+string" }).data();
// Object {}
$('<object>', { id:"foo", 'data-foo':"some+data+string" }).data();
// Object {foo:"some+data+string"}
```

So... why does it not create the HTML attribute `data` since it is not a `data-xxxx` attribute name, and therefore does not create any actual data?

### Update

I'll reiterate what's written in this question once more.

[...] If I write

```
$('<div>', { id:"foo", 'class':"bar" });
// <div id="foo" class="bar"></div>
```

However

```
$('<object>', { id:"foo", data:"some+data+string" });
// [ <object id="foo"></object> ]
```

**where I expected the output to be**

```
// [ <object id="foo" data="some+data+string"></object> ]
```

... and once again, I know about `.data`.

Why doesn't `$('<div>', { data: 'foo' })` create `<div data="foo"></div>`, or in other word, why does it ignore the attribute altogether when creating the element?

### Edit

For all those arguing that `data` is not a valid HTML attribute, well, [it is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-data).

### Update

As of today, the solution I am using for this use case is

```
$('<div>', {
  attr: {
    data: 'foo'
  }
});
```

Comment: The object passed when creating elements contains attributes and/or methods, and the attribute name is `data-foo`, not `data`. Just because the jQuery `data()` function takes the second part of the data attribute as an argument doesn't mean that it would work that way anywhere else.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kC9QG/

Comment: @adeneo can you read the question once more? This has nothing to do with me wanting to create `data-foo`.

Comment: Why do you end your last examples with `.data()`?

Comment: @j08691 to show the output of the data object, and to show how inconsistent it is, since `{ data:'foo }` does not create anything and `{ 'data-foo':'foo' }` creates `{ foo:'foo' }`

Comment: **Note**: it is not because you can't read a question and are upset when someone corrects you that you are justified to downvote a question. Just saying.

Comment: It's because jQuery only creates the data attribute if it's valid, and it's only valid it there is a hyphen followed by an identifier, as in `data-something`, the spec clearly states `data-*`, not `data`

Comment: @adeneo again, I **know** that. So why, if `data` does not contains an hypen, doesn't it create an HTML attribute called `data`? An HTML attribute called `data` is perfectly fine and and also follows the HTML specs.

Comment: Because data is also a method, and when method names are used, the method is called, and the data method does not set the attributes.

Comment: And `data=""` is not a valid attribute -> http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes, it has to have a hyphen followed by at least one character, but why do we even botter, you're not listening to anything we say ?

Comment: @adeneo you are confusing data attributes (i.e. `data-*`) and an attribute whose name is `data`, which is a legal attribute name.

Comment: @adeneo http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-data

Comment: So be more specific in the question, object tags do have a data attribute, but generally that is not a valid attribute, and you're mixing it with HTML5 data attributes, so it's hard to see, **but again** jQuery will use the `data()` method when `data` is used like that, so I guess it doesn't account for the rarely used data attribute for object tags.

Comment: Had you asked the question outlining exactly why you're using the object tag and what you're expecting in a ***much*** better way, me and @j08691 wouldn't have misunderstood you, and you're being somewhat rude when it's you that are not able to get your point across.

Comment: @adeneo We could argue a long time over this. However, your argument can be turned upside down; my original question has not been edited, I only added a preamble and some updates. The question is clear enough if you stop looking in the wrong direction. BTW, my rudeness comes from the experience that I have on SO for a while now (and not only from questions that I ask, but that I see to other users), as people are quick to make a (wrong) opinion and lowers the content quality of this site. Not all people are native english persons. It *is* the Internet after all. We don't all live in the US.

Comment: Well, that's true, I'm not a native english speaker and still didn't understand the question, but I somewhat get it now after all the comments, and the answer is simple, jQuery looks for methods in the object passed *first*, that's why you can use `on()` and `css()` directly in the object, [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k8QDT/), and `data()` is a method as well, and it only sets data internally, and jQuery has to look for the methods before it uses the keys as attributes, as it would be too late after the attributes are set, and if the key matches a method, no attribute is set.

Comment: @adeneo well, *that* is a good answer. Why is it a comment? :)

Comment: Give me a second to post something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating an element and passing an object with attributes and methods, any jQuery method is valid, so you can do

```
$('<div />', { 
    id      : "foo",  
    'class' : "bar",
    text    : "test",          // jQuery text() is called,
    html    : '<span></span>', // jQuery html() is called,
    css     : {                // jQuery css() is called,
        color: 'red'
    },
    on : {                     // calls jQuery's .on('click' ...
        click: function() {
             alert
        }
    }
});
```

In the same way, `data=""` is not a common attribute, it's only valid on a few elements, like `<object>`, and jQuery doesn't seem to account for this, so you can't set a `data=""` attribute as jQuery will catch the `data()` method first.

In other words, this doesn't work, instead it sets the internal data object using data()

```
$('<object />', {data : 'somedata'});
```

A rather strange workaround is that this seems to be case sensitive, so jQuery will only look for the methods if the key is all lowercase, and on the other hand, jQuery attr() will always lowercase attributes, so doing any of these

```
$('<object>', { id:"foo", 'Data' : "some+data+string" });
$('<object>', { id:"foo", 'daTa' : "some+data+string" });
```

will actually work, and the attribute will be lower cased when set, so you end up with

```
<object id="foo" data="some+data+string"></object>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k8QDT/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Comment: @YanickRochon - You're welcome, and it is really a rather interesting question on how jQuery works, it was just a little hard to grok at first.