# Append select box options dynamically with attributes

Tags: jquery

I need to append extra data to my select box options. here is my code.

**Html:**

```
<select id="questionNumber" class="form-control">
   <option>Select Number</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$.each(result.data, function (key, value) {
    $("#questionNumber").append($('<option>', {
        value: value.id,
        text: value.number
    }));
});
```

So i can add value and text but i want to append attributes also to this appended option 
like

```
data-marks = value.mark
```

So my expected result would be like

```
<select id="questionNumber" class="form-control">
   <option>Select Number</option>
   <option value="170" data-mark="2">1</option>
   <option value="171" data-mark="3">2</option>
</select>
```

What should i do for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery create a new element with \`data\` HTML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886101/jquery-create-a-new-element-with-data-html-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/u5vek2jc/

```js
var result = {data:[
 {
   id:"5",
    number: "5"
  },
  {
   id: "89",
    number: "89"
  }
]}
$.each(result.data, function (key, value) {
    $("#questionNumber").append($('<option>', {
        value: value.id,
        text: value.number,
        'data-mark': value.id
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="questionNumber" class="form-control">
   <option>Select Number</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `data` attribute to the HTML you generate. Also note that you can amend the logic so that the DOM is only updated once, instead of inside each iteration. Try this:

```
var html = result.data.map(function(o) {
  return `<option value="${o.id}" data-mark="${o.mark}">${o.number}</option>`;
}).join('');
$("#questionNumber").append(html);
```

Comment: As I mentioned on your answer, using `data()` means that the attribute will not appear in the DOM. The OP stated that as a requirement. It's possible that `data()` may meet their needs too

Answer (score 1):

iterate over your data to create options, and then append it to your select element

```
$html='';
$.each(result.data, function (key, value) {
    html +='<option value="' + value.id + '"  data-mark="'+value.mark+'">' + value.number + '</option>';
});
$("#questionNumber").append(html);
```

Comment: @31piy this is exactly what the OP wants, and is much faster than performing a DOM operation once per iteration

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar example and more complete:

```
var cadena_user_pais = ($(this).attr('id')).split("_");
var id_user_pais = cadena_user_pais[2];
var request = 'view_tipoNIF';
//tipo de NIF
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_single_users.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{id_user_pais:id_user_pais,request:request},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                //alert('hola');
                var html='';
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    html +='<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.NIF + '</option>';
                });             
                $("#select_user_tipoNIF").append(html);
            }   //success
        });
```